# Exchange Web Services - Inline Images to outside Email Clients not rendering

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to receive/send emails. I am sending embedded images in the email to navigate users to another page. However, when sending to other emails clients like gmail and yahoo, the images are not being set as html, but text. I created a console app below to demonstrate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = getExchangeService(NetworkCreds.Credentials);

        // Create the HTML body with the content identifier of the attachment.
        string html = @"<html>
                 <head>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                    <img width=100 height=100 id=""1"" src=""cid:Party.jpg"">
                 </body>
                 </html>";

        // Create the email message.
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
        email.Subject = "Test Email";
        email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html);
        email.ToRecipients.Add("test@gmail.com");

        // Add the attachment to the local copy of the email message.
        string file = @"C:\projects\Party.jpg";
        email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Party.jpg", file);
        email.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
        email.Attachments[0].ContentId = "Party.jpg";

        // Save a copy of the email, add the attachment, and then send the email. This method results in three calls to EWS.
        email.SendAndSaveCopy();
    }
```

When I receive the message in outlook it works fine but in gmail it only has the following text in the body: [cid:Party.jpg] with the file attachment below. I know Gmail and other clients have extensive processing of images and that may the case of why it's not displaying correctly. **My question is if inline images can be sent from exchange web services to other clients and be processed correctly?**

Comment: What the content type of the Message it should be Content-Type: multipart/alternative; . It maybe that on the Exchange side you have remote domain rule set so it only send Message with Text body part to those domains. If you look at Message Tracking for one of the Message your sending that should give you more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fix this kind of thing

```
bodyText = bodyText.Replace("cid:" + fileAttachment.ContentId, fileAttachment.Name);
```

Be sure to attach the file as "Image 001.png" or whatever it is, then you can resend this e-mail with images in tact :)

Answer (score -1):

I know that i am a bit late but maybe someone else will stuck at a similar problem and this could help solving the problem.

You could set the image as base64 encoded image.

In my case i wanted to load a preview of an existing email in a browser control.
Everything worked except showing the images. But replacing them to base64 encoded strings worked perfectly.

In this example following code should work as described:

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
email.Subject = "Test Email";
email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html);
email.ToRecipients.Add("test@gmail.com");
// Add the attachment to the local copy of the email message.
string file = @"C:\projects\Party.jpg";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("Party.jpg", file).Load(stream);
byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
// Convert byte[] to Base64 String
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
stream.close();
email.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
email.Attachments[0].ContentId = "Party.jpg";

string html = @"<html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                <img width=100 height=100 id=""1"" src=""data: image/jpg;base64, " + base64String + """>
                </body>
                </html>";
```